# render() fucntion not working properly in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await

I am using the MERN stack for developing a website. I used passport.js for local authentication. The user logins through a login form on `'/login'` on the frontend. Once the user clicks on the submit button I prevent its default behaviour and send an axios post request at `'/login'` on the backend. Once the user is authenticated I send the user to `'/products'` on the frontend. To know if the user is authenticated or not, I send an axios get request at `'/login'` at the backend in the `compoundDidMount()` function which sets the state property `loggedIn` to `true` if user is authenticated, else `false`. If I once again visit `'/login'` route on the frontend I should be redirected to `'/products'` on the frontend without rendering the code in `else` statement (login form) based on the code in the `render()` funtion. But first, the code in the `else` statement (login form) is getting rendered for a fraction of a second and then it's rendering the component on `'/products'`. Why is this happening? I don't want the login form to be rendered once I am logged in, on visiting the `'/login'` route on the frontend. Here is my code.

`login.js` (Login component)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Redirect} from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';

class Login extends Component {
    state = {
        email: "",
        password: "",
        loggedIn: false
    }
    
    handleLogin = event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const data = {
            email: this.state.email, 
            password: this.state.password
        };
        axios.post('/login', data)
        .then(response => {
            // console.log("response status code: ", response.status);
            if(response.status === 200) {
                // this.setState({loggedIn: true});
                this.props.history.push('/products');
            }
        })
        .catch(error => console.log('error is :', error));
    }

    handleChange = event => {
        const property  = event.target.name,
              value     = event.target.value;
        this.setState({[property]: value});
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.getLoggedInStatus();
    }

    getLoggedInStatus = () => {
        axios.get('/login')
        .then(response => {
            console.log("response.data is: ", response.data.loggedIn);
            this.setState({loggedIn: response.data.loggedIn});
            // if(response.data.loggedIn)
            //     this.props.history.push('/products');
        })
        .catch(error => console.log("error is : ", error));
        // return loggedIn;
    }

    render() { 
        // this.getLoggedInStatus();
        // console.log("loggedIn is: ", this.state.loggedIn);
        if(this.state.loggedIn) {
            console.log('Working');
            return <Redirect to="/products" />
        }
        else {
            console.log('not working');
            return (
                <div className="container d-flex justify-content-center mt-5">
                    <form className="w-50 mt-2" action="/login" method="POST" onSubmit={this.handleLogin}>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
                            <input type="email" className="form-control" name="email" onChange={this.handleChange} id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" required/>
                            <small id="emailHelp" className="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
                            <input type="password" className="form-control" name="password" onChange={this.handleChange} id="exampleInputPassword1" required/>
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            );
        } 
    }
}
 
export default Login;
```

backend code

```
router.get('/login', (request, response) => {
    response.json({loggedIn: request.isAuthenticated()});
});

router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local'), (request, response) => {
    if(request.isAuthenticated())
        // response.json('successful login');
        response.status(200).send({message: 'successful login'});
    else {
        console.log('Not authenticated');
        response.status(404).send({message: 'unsuccessful login'});
    }
});
```

Comment: I will suggest to keep the information whether user is loggedIn for not in the localStorage and before making the call in componentDidMount , check if the data is present in the local Storage , if yes , dont call backend direct Redirect else call backend . This will reduce the delay of unnecessary backend call !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Suggestion

Add an extra property (i.e loading) to your state object to track if the login should render or not (and perhaps adding a loading component). See code comment as well.

#### Example:

```
// Your component state
state = {
        email: "",
        password: "",
        loggedIn: false,
        loading: true // default state
};


// Your getLoggedInStatus code

 getLoggedInStatus = () => {
    axios.get('/login')
    .then(response => {
        console.log("response.data is: ", response.data.loggedIn);
        this.setState({loggedIn: response.data.loggedIn, loading: false}); // update loading state to false
    })
    .catch(error => console.log("error is : ", error));
    // return loggedIn;
}


// Your render code

render() { 
        // this.getLoggedInStatus();
        // console.log("loggedIn is: ", this.state.loggedIn);
        if(this.state.loggedIn) {
            console.log('Working');
            return <Redirect to="/products" />
        }
        else {
            if(this.state.loading) {
               return(<div> Loading...</div>); // Have something more fancy here
            } else {
              return (
                <div className="container d-flex justify-content-center mt-5">
                    <form className="w-50 mt-2" action="/login" method="POST" onSubmit={this.handleLogin}>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
                            <input type="email" className="form-control" name="email" onChange={this.handleChange} id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" required/>
                            <small id="emailHelp" className="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
                            <input type="password" className="form-control" name="password" onChange={this.handleChange} id="exampleInputPassword1" required/>
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            );
            }
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use `isLoading` state and show a spinner while the request is in process.

---

```
state = {
        email: "",
        password: "",
        loggedIn: false
        idLoading: false
    }

...

getLoggedInStatus = () => {
        this.setState({ isLoading: true });
        axios.get('/login')
        .then(response => {
            console.log("response.data is: ", response.data.loggedIn);
            this.setState({loggedIn: response.data.loggedIn, isLoading: false});
            // if(response.data.loggedIn)
            //     this.props.history.push('/products');
        })
        .catch(error => console.log("error is : ", error));
        // return loggedIn;
    }

...

render() { 
        // this.getLoggedInStatus();
        // console.log("loggedIn is: ", this.state.loggedIn);
        if(this.state.loggedIn) {
            console.log('Working');
            return <Redirect to="/products" />
        }
        else {
            if (this.state.isLoading) {
              <div>Loading...</div>
            }
            return (
                <div className="container d-flex justify-content-center mt-5">
                    <form className="w-50 mt-2" action="/login" method="POST" onSubmit={this.handleLogin}>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
                            <input type="email" className="form-control" name="email" onChange={this.handleChange} id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" required/>
                            <small id="emailHelp" className="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
                            <input type="password" className="form-control" name="password" onChange={this.handleChange} id="exampleInputPassword1" required/>
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            );
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

React component life-cycle methods are called in the following sequence:

Constructor -> componentWillMount -> render -> componentDidMount

Every time when you go to login page a **NEW** instance of your `Login` component gets created. Your "implicit" constructor initializes a new instance with `state.loggedIn` to `false` by

```
state = {
        email: "",
        password: "",
        loggedIn: false
    }
```

This causes your render function to show login form and call `componentDidMount` which sends a request to the backend. While your component is waiting for a response from the backend - login form is shown on the screen. Once response comes in - you set `state.loggedIn` to true which causes another `render` call and this time your component redirects to a `products` page.

In order to fix your problem you need to move `loggedIn` property from component state level to application state level by using something like [redux](https://redux.js.org/) or any other approach to manage front-end application state.